# Find $\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \sqrt{n} \int_0^{\pi/2} \sqrt{19 \sin^{2n}{x} + 2\cos^{2n}{x} }dx$

Tags: real-analysis, limits

Find $$\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \sqrt{n} \int_0^{\pi/2} \sqrt{19 \sin^{2n}{x} + 2\cos^{2n}{x} }dx$$

I have try to prove $\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \sqrt{n} \int_0^{\pi/2} \sqrt{19 \sin^{2n}{x} + 2\cos^{2n}{x} }dx = 0$ through the clamping theorem. My ideal was prove $\int_0^{\pi/2} \sqrt{19 \sin^{2n}{x} + 2\cos^{2n}{x} }dx \le \frac{a}{n^{\alpha}}$ through inequality, but I still stuck in this ideal ( Don't have any idea about not only how to find $\alpha$ also what inequality will use. )

Can you help me, or recommend for me another approach ? Thank u so much

Comment: https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c7h2223811p16924944   maybe help you.

Comment: @Riemann Thank u so much